# Conditional data binding on table

Tags: javascript, sapui5

I have a table with {Orders} as column. Inside my metadata.xml, I am getting {status} entity.

```
    <smartTable:SmartTable id="table" beforeRebindTable="handleBeforeRebindTable">
            <Table>
                  <columns>
                    <Column>
                        <header>
                            <Text text="ManufacturingOrder" id="order"/>
                        </header>
                    </Column>        
                </columns>

                <items>
                    <ColumnListItem >
                        <cells>
                            <ObjectIdentifier title="{Order}" />
                        </cells>
                    </ColumnListItem>
                </items>
            </Table>
        </smartTable:SmartTable>
```

Now, I want to display only those orders, having status=1. (statuses can be of multiple types).

For this, I had used handleBeforeRebindTable as

```
    handleBeforeRebindTable: function(oEvent) {

        var oTableItems = this.getView().byId("table").getItems();
        var oItemData;
        var sStatus = "status";
        for (var i = 1; i < oTableItems.length; i++) {
            oItemData = oTableItems[i].getBindingContext().getProperty();
            if (this.sStatus === "1") {
                oTableItems[i].setVisible(true);
            }  else {
                oTableItems[i].setVisible(!oItemData.Active);
            }
        }

    },
```

However, somehow it do not work. Can anyone tell me what am I doing wrong or any other way to do this?

Comment: So, how it doesn't work? Nothing is shown? or everything is shown?

Comment: Everything is shown, in short, no filtering takes place

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The BeforeRebindTable event is fired before the binding of the table. Therefore the table does not contain data yet. But you can add a filter in the event to the binding.

```
handleBeforeRebindTable: function(oEvent) {
    var oParameters = oEvent.getParameter("bindingParams").parameters;
    oParameters.filters = oParameters.filters.concat(new sap.ui.model.Filter("status", sap.ui.model.FilterOperator.EQ, "1"));
}
```